# Restrict drag and drop to a path object (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building an interactive tutorial on alpine skiing. The missing element is to get the  **drag and drop behaviour** to work as I want. When you drag the skier (i.e. an image object appended on a svg), it jumps, and that is not what I want. Is there a way to fix this?

The second thing is that I want the drag behaviour to only drag along the hill (i.e. the path object) is there a way to achieve this behaviour? Here is my code:

```js
var skierIconSvg = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/94/94150.svg";
var width = 800;
var height = 600;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
svg.attr('width', width)
svg.attr('height', height)

// linjekonstruktor
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })

// mine data
var lineData = [{
    "x": 30,
    "y": 60
  },
  {
    "x": 550,
    "y": 225
  },
];


var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([60, 225])
  .range([60, 225]);


var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale);

svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);


var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", line(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none")


var skier = svg.append("image")
  .attr("id", "skier")
  .attr("href", skierIconSvg)
  .attr("x", -40)
  .attr("y", -80)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + Object.values(lineData[0]) + "), rotate(7.5, 0, 0)")
  .call(
    // Attach drag event handlers to the circle
    d3
    .drag()
    .on('start', start)
    .on('drag', dragged)
  )
  .on("click", clicked);

var infobBox = svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .text("HELLO, trykk for utøveren for å starte")
  .style("font-size", 20 + "px");


function clicked(d, i) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // dragged

  d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + Object.values(lineData[1]) + "), , rotate(7.5, 0, 0)");

  d3.selectAll("text")
    .text("Begynt!")
}

function start() {
  var current = d3.select(this)
  deltaX = current.attr("x") - d3.event.x;
  deltaY = current.attr("y") - d3.event.y;
};

function dragged() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", d3.event.x)
    .attr("y", d3.event.y);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, since we intend for StackOverflow to be a database of general questions and answers, and to keep the process easier, it would be great if your question could consist of only one part. Currently, you have two subquestions - the jumpy behaviour and the movement across the line. Please refrain from asking multiple questions at once, as it can be treated as a cause to close your - in other aspects perfectly good - question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `start` handler you compute the delta, but don't use it in the `dragged` handler. The dragged handler should look more like this:

```
function dragged() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", d3.event.x + deltaX)
    .attr("y", d3.event.y + deltaY);
};
```

Even with this, you may have some surprising mouse behavior as a result of the `rotate` translation you've applied on the skier, which will make him go out of the mouse's reach slowly. If you don't need it, the simplest option is to remove it, which I did in my answer.

```js
var skierIconSvg = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/94/94150.svg";
var width = 800;
var height = 600;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
svg.attr('width', width)
svg.attr('height', height)

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })

// mine data
var lineData = [{
    "x": 30,
    "y": 60
  },
  {
    "x": 550,
    "y": 225
  },
];


var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([60, 225])
  .range([60, 225]);


var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale);

svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);


var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", line(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none")


var skier = svg.append("image")
  .attr("id", "skier")
  .attr("href", skierIconSvg)
  .attr("x", -40)
  .attr("y", -80)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + Object.values(lineData[0]) + ")")
  .call(
    // Attach drag event handlers to the circle
    d3
    .drag()
    .on('start', start)
    .on('drag', dragged)
  )
  .on("click", clicked);

var infobBox = svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .text("HELLO, trykk for utøveren for å starte")
  .style("font-size", 20 + "px");


function clicked(d, i) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // dragged

  d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + Object.values(lineData[1]) + ")");

  d3.selectAll("text")
    .text("Begynt!")
}

function start() {
  var current = d3.select(this)
  deltaX = current.attr("x") - d3.event.x;
  deltaY = current.attr("y") - d3.event.y;
};

function dragged() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", d3.event.x + deltaX)
    .attr("y", d3.event.y + deltaY);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cheers. It worked. I am a bit confused about why I need to calculate the delta. Any good explanation?

Comment: The delta is the distance from the top-left of the image and your cursor. When moving, we add it each time. Otherwise, dragging would jump to the top left of the image each time. See https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/18/d3-js-drag-and-drop-tutorial/ for a more detailled explaination.